# Definition of a compact linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

We know that if $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces, then a linear $T:X\to Y$ is compact if $T(B_X)$ is relatively compact, i.e. $\overline{T(B_X)}$ is compact. My question is why it is not defined as $T(B_X)$ is compact? Does this imply $Y$ is finite dimensional? Any comment in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: If $T$ is surjective then $Y$ will be finite dimensional.

Comment: That is true for usual definition also.

Comment: Because $\overline{T(B_X)}$ compact does not imply $T(B_X)$ compact.

Comment: That is fine. My question is why compact operator is not defined as "T is compact if $T(B_X)$ is compact"?

Comment: If you define $T(B_X)$ as compact and if $T$ is surjective then by open mapping theorem image of open unit ball $U\subseteq X$ under $T$ will be open. Since normed spaces are connected and $T(U)$ is compact(hence closed) we have $T(U)=Y$ but compactness of $T(U)$ implies $Y$ is compact . Hence $Y$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: If $T$ is not surjective and if you define $T(B_X)$ as compact then $im(T)$ will be finite dimensional.

Answer (score 2):

If $B_X$ is the closed unit ball (which is the standard notation) then  it is possible for $T(B_X)$ itself to be compact, contrary to some of the claims made in the previous comments. In fact, if $X$ is reflexive that this is always true. Let $\|x_n\| \leq 1$ and $Tx_n \to y$. Then there is a subnet $\{x_{n_{k}}\}$ which converges weakly, say to $z$. The $\{T(x_{n_{k}})\} \to Tz$ weakly which implies $y=Tz$. Thus $T(B_X)$ is closed. Thus the new definition you are suggesting is equivalent to the usual definition in reflexive spaces. A counterexample in the general case is the following: let $Tf(x)=\int_0^{x}f(t) \, dt$ for $f\in C[0,1]$. The $T$ is compact but the image of the closed unit ball is not closed.  [Take a nondiferentiable function and approximate it by polynomials. These polynomials are in $T(B_X)$ but their limit is not].

Comment: Yes. It is absolutely correct. actually I wanted to know the reason behind the definition of compact operators. Definitely for reflexive spaces the one I said works. Was the original definition given for making the class of compact operators large or there is any othe reason behind it.

Comment: The example I have give at the end of my answer is special case of an integral operator with a square intergable kernel. Such operators are important in applications. Though they are compact, the image of the unit ball itself may not b e compact. I hope this convinces you that the usual definition is to be preferred to your definition.